# Simple PDF created with iTextSharp cannot be opened by Acrobat Reader?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I create simple test PDF document using iTextSharp. I'm just using PdfContentByte to show some text. This is the code:

```
    Document document = new Document();
    Stream outStream = new FileStream("D:\\aaa\\test.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outStream);
    document.Open();
    PdfContentByte to = writer.DirectContent;
    to.BeginText();
    to.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(), 12);
    to.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
    to.ShowText("aaa");
    to.EndText();
    document.Close();
    outStream.Close();
```

The file is created but when I try to open it(using Acrobat Reader), all I get is following message:

> There was an error opening this
>   document. There was a problem reading
>   this document (14).

Where is the problem ? How do I fix it? Thank you

Comment: Any ideas ? I guess this is just something very easy, something like my very stupid mistake but I just cant see it...

Comment: I runned your code and didn't get any error, which version of ITextSharp are you using ?

Comment: Not even when trying to open the generated file ?? I don't get error when I run c# code, only when I open generated file.

Comment: no, it showed the "aaa" at the bottom perfectly fine

Comment: @dada686: strange... What may cause it ? I'll try to delete the file and restart VS, then run it again and generate the PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was solved after restarting VS. No code change was made.

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to replicate the problem you're encountering, but please take into account potential leaks of resources due to any exceptional conditions you may encounter and properly `Dispose()` those objects as such:

```
    using (Stream outStream = new FileStream("D:\\aaa\\test.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outStream);

        document.Open();
        try
        {
            PdfContentByte to = writer.DirectContent;

            to.BeginText();
            try
            {
                to.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(), 12);
                to.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
                to.ShowText("aaa");
            }
            finally
            {
                to.EndText();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            document.Close();
        }
    }
```